# Apply morphological operation (closing) on a separate region?

Tags: scikit-image, image-morphology

I am using a few filters ending with skeleton to isolate areas of an image. Ideally, the skeleton would only contain loops of certain size, but that is not the case and many parasitic branches creep in; I use labeling to isolate individual loops in the skeleton, but they contain these artifacts:

[image: region from skeleton example]

To remove that noise, I would apply closing operation, but it would have to be restricted on a single label at time, so that regions with thin boundaries in-between would not get blended. Is there a function for this, or do I simply extract the label image from `skimage.measure.regionprops(...)`, using `regionprop.image` on each individual region returned and work with that? I am concerned about performance if I go down to handling each pixel separately. Any ideas welcome.

**PS (edit):** the image show is only a small part of the image analyzed, there is around 1k labeled regions. That's why I am also looking at performance.

**PS2:** this is a larger portion of the image:

[image: larger-image]

Comment: First of all you might think about mentioning, which library you are using. Second, concernint the problem, I would partition the image into subimages with overlap an re-merge after the operation. Did so myself for a combined open-close-action, and it worked nicely.

Comment: @gilgamash see the scikit-image tag

Comment: Ah yes, sorry for not realizing that. A loop with single label extraction imho is not feasible, concerning the runtime. Creation of subimages with overlaps works, but is costly, too, esp. if there are that many labels. What about running a hough circle detection? For that, the artifacts might not eben be real disturbances, considering their geometric appearance..

Comment: A for-loop over a thousand elements costs you almost nothing, so I'd use that, grab the sub-image from each region (that functionality is already available), and replace it with the processed image (coordinates are also available in the regionprop).

Comment: The skeleton is always an unstable operator. Do you want to separate the different cells?

Comment: @FiReTiTi Yes, separation and statistics on individual cells is the goal. In what sense you say "unstable"?

Comment: If the cells are not overlapping too often, a top-hat followed by an ultimate eroded is an easy way to segment them. Else, if you are interested by the cell size distribution, you can use a granulometry (no need for segmentation). The skeleton is unstable in the sense that a single pixel on the border can generate a branch.

Comment: @FiReTiTi I am ultimately interested in granulometric distribution, yes; granulometry needs some kind of segmentation, I use adaptive threshold followed by skeletonization (and then use skeleton loops as cells). Link for the type of granulometry you seem to suggest (without segmentation) would be helpful.

Comment: The main interest of granulometry is to not do a segmentation, except if you want to be highly specific. You can probably apply your granulometry just after the thresholding. Can we see the original image or at least a big crop of it?

Comment: @FiReTiTi: added a larger crop of the original. I know you can do granulometry w/o segmentation with FFT/wavelet analysis and such, but that is not precise enough for my needs. I need size & circularity statistics (and perhaps also some dealing with partially occluded particles, by setting limit on circularity and such).